# Extract URL from string in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract the URL from a string stored in a cell.

In the example below, the string is in `A2` and I only want to extract `"abcd.co.uk"`. Can you please help?

```
abcd company
. local technicians
.  solutions
. Experts ¡n all areas
abcd ***abcd.co.uk***
```

I have tried multiple ways but could not get it to work.

```
Sub url()
    abc = Range("A2")

    t_temp = Split(abc, ".co.uk")
    Range("A3") = t_temp
    t_temp_text2 = Mid(t_temp, 1, InStr(t_temp, " "))
End Sub
```

Comment: Your best approach here would be to use a regular expression. Difficult to suggest what pattern would be appropriate without some more example URL's

Answer (score 0):

I see the cell content to be searched in has been updated

And so here comes the consequently revised code

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetUrl2()
Dim abc As Range
Dim urlString As String
Dim iPosIni As Integer, iPosEnd As Integer

Set abc = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") '<== change it to your needs

iPosEnd = InStrRev(abc.Value, "***")
iPosIni = InStrRev(Mid(abc.Value, 1, iPosEnd), "***") + 3

urlString = Mid(abc.Value, iPosIni, iPosEnd - iPosIni)

End Sub
```

that can be shortened, at the expense of readability, as follows

```
Sub GetUrl3()
Dim abc As Range
Dim urlString As String
Set abc = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") '<== change it to your needs

urlString = Mid(abc.Value, _
                InStrRev(Mid(abc.Value, 1, InStrRev(abc.Value, "***")), "***") + 3, _
                InStrRev(abc.Value, "***") - _
                (InStrRev(Mid(abc.Value, 1, InStrRev(abc.Value, "***")), "***") + 3) _
                )

End Sub
```

At which point I think you'd rather confine that code in a function to be called by your main code like follows

```
Sub Main()
Dim urlString As String

urlString = GetUrl(ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value)

End Sub


Function GetUrl(strng As String) As String

GetUrl = Mid(strng, _
                InStrRev(Mid(strng, 1, InStrRev(strng, "***")), "***") + 3, _
                InStrRev(strng, "***") - _
                (InStrRev(Mid(strng, 1, InStrRev(strng, "***")), "***") + 3) _
                )

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.. but the urlString returns blank.Can you suggest

Comment: I tested with "abcd company . local technicians . solutions . Experts ¡n all areas abcd dabcd.co.uk2" in cell A2 of the active sheet and it works.  be sure that ActiveSheet is actually the sheet whose cell A2 contains what you need and that the url is the last info in the cell.  step through code and query attempts (InStrRev(abc.Value, " ")) in immediate window

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic regex example:

```
Sub GetDomains()

   Dim reg As Object, tester As String, ms, m

   Set reg = CreateObject("VBscript.Regexp")

   tester = Range("A1").Value

   reg.IgnoreCase = True
   reg.MultiLine = False
   reg.Pattern = "([a-z0-9.-]{1,}\.[a-z0-9.-]{2,}(\.[a-z0-9.-]{2,})?)"

   Set ms = reg.Execute(tester)
   If Not ms Is Nothing Then
    For Each m In ms
        Debug.Print m.Value
    Next m
   End If

End Sub
```