# Finding whole word/URL in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an ADODB stream object to write content to a file. I'm doing an on-the-fly to HTML conversion. What I could not find out so far is, how can I automatically wrap URLs in `<a>` tags?

For example, I have a string like:

```
Foo bar https://www.google.com foo bar.
```

I can search for the `https://` but how can I match/select the whole URL with VBA?

```
Dim fs As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fs.Type = 2
fs.Charset = "utf-8"
fs.Open

fs.WriteText mystring
    
fs.SaveToFile filename, 2
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Stefan

Comment: Will [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874007/extract-url-from-string-in-vba-excel) help? For more links, search google for `VBA Extract URL from string`

Comment: Regex should work, a pattern like say `(https:\/\/[\S]{1,})` (untested and assuming all your URL starts with `https://`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot, [@Raymond Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15597936/raymond-wu) and [wellsr.com](https://www.wellsr.com) (see [Introduction to VBA RegEx](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/#regex) article). This has helped.

My solution is:

```
Function htmlConform(x As String)

    Dim debugging As Boolean
    debugging = False

    htmlConform = Replace(x, "<", "&lt;")
    htmlConform = Replace(x, ">", "&gt;")
    htmlConform = Replace(x, "&", "&amp;")
    
    Dim r As Match
    Dim mcolResults As MatchCollection
    
    Dim strPattern As String
    strPattern = "(https:\/\/[\S]{1,})"
    Set mcolResults = RegEx(x, strPattern, , , True)
    
    If Not mcolResults Is Nothing Then
        For Each r In mcolResults
            htmlConform = Replace(x, r, "<a href='" & r & "'>link</a>")
            If debugging = True Then Debug.Print "RegEx match: " & r
        Next r
    End If

End Function

'***************************************************************************
' Regex function wrapping the Regex object from "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" Object Library
'***************************************************************************
Function RegEx(strInput As String, strPattern As String, _
    Optional GlobalSearch As Boolean, Optional MultiLine As Boolean, _
    Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean) As MatchCollection
    
    Dim mcolResults As MatchCollection
    Dim objRegEx As New RegExp
    
    If strPattern <> vbNullString Then
        
        With objRegEx
            .Global = GlobalSearch
            .MultiLine = MultiLine
            .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
    
        If objRegEx.Test(strInput) Then
            Set mcolResults = objRegEx.Execute(strInput)
            Set RegEx = mcolResults
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Beautiful! I would've replaced the pattern with: 

`(http.?:\/\/[\S]{1,})`

for URLs to get both HTTP and HTTPS urls or even this monstrosity to get URLs and IPs (even with ports): 

`(http.?:\/\/[\S]{1,})|((?!(10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])\.|192\.168\.).*)(?!255\.255\.255\.255)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}(:\d+)?)`